# Travis build for go targeting Wasm

Tags: go, travis-ci, webassembly

I'm building a go module targeting Wasm that I need to test.

**Current configuration**

The `travis.yml` config:

```
language: go
go:
  - 1.11.x
before_install:
  - curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
  - dep ensure
```

And the following `makefile`:

```
all: deps test 
deps:
    GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go get ./...
test: 
    GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go test ./...
test-cover:
    $(GOPATH)/bin/mockgen -source=dom/dom.go -destination=mock/dom.go -package=mock
    $(GOPATH)/bin/mockgen -source=vnode.go -destination=mock/node.go -package=mock
    GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go test ./... -coverprofile=cover.out
    go tool cover -html=cover.out
```

And my `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/marvinfrachet/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/marvinfrachet/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/t0/7bv6yclx1d913wtl6rdsvjtr0000gn/T/go-build435765871=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

**The problem**

On my build, I'm having the following error:

```
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go get ./...
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go test ./...
fork/exec /tmp/go-build540008292/b001/go-vdom-wasm.test: exec format error
FAIL    github.com/mfrachet/go-vdom-wasm    0.004s
?       github.com/mfrachet/go-vdom-wasm/dom    [no test files]
fork/exec /tmp/go-build540008292/b118/helpers.test: exec format error
FAIL    github.com/mfrachet/go-vdom-wasm/helpers    0.005s
?       github.com/mfrachet/go-vdom-wasm/mock   [no test files]
```

https://travis-ci.org/mfrachet/go-vdom-wasm

On a locale machine, it's working great and my tests all pass.

I think the problem is due to the `GOOS=js` that doesn't seem to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you are missing `go_js_wasm_exec` in your `$PATH`, which is required when launching `go test` with `GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm`.

It is located in the `misc/wasm` directory of the go SDK so this could fix your travis build:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOROOT)/misc/wasm"
```

Note that you also need `node` in your `$PATH`.

Another way that works for me is using the `-exec` option of `go test`:

```sh
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go test -exec="node $(go env GOROOT)/misc/wasm/wasm_exec"
```

But it is only useful for giving additional options to node (not possible when using `go_js_wasm_exec`).